# Multiple nested v-for loops filtering for unique data

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm looking for some help looping through some data with nested v-for loops, eliminating the duplicate states, and throwing the corresponding counties under the matching states. Basically, I'm trying to have the outcome like this:

company 1
Areas Served
State 1 no duplicates
All Counties Matching State 1 under company 1
State 2 no duplicates
All Counties Matching State 2 under company 1


company 2
Areas Served
State 1 no duplicates
All Counties Matching State 1 under company 2
State 2 no duplicates
All Counties Matching State 2 under company 2

I've tried a few different computed methods with no luck, and the data structure with the duplicates is throwing me off. Any help would be appreciated!

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-rnrh7

```
<template>
  <div class="companies">
    <div v-for="ac in acList" :key="ac.Id">
      <div class="post-block">
        <h2 class="mb0">
          {{ac.Name}} -
          <small>{{ac.Country}}</small>
        </h2>
        <h3>Areas Served</h3>

        <div v-for="region in ac.Regions">
          {{region.RegionName + ", " + region.RegionGroupName}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Companies",
  data() {
    return {
      acList: [
        {
          Name: "Name 1",
          Address: "Address 1",
          City: "New Orleans",
          State: "LA",
          PostalCode: "70130",
          Country: "USA",
          Regions: [
            {
              Country: "USA",
              RegionName: "Humphreys",
              RegionGroupName: "MS",
              RegionType: "County"
            },
            {
              Country: "USA",
              RegionName: "Smith",
              RegionGroupName: "MS",
              RegionType: "County"
            },
            {
              Country: "USA",
              RegionName: "Plaquemines",
              RegionGroupName: "LA",
              RegionType: "County"
            },
            {
              Country: "USA",
              RegionName: "West Feliciana",
              RegionGroupName: "LA",
              RegionType: "County"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          Name: "Name 2",
          Address: "Address 2",
          City: "New York",
          State: "NY",
          PostalCode: "10001",
          Country: "USA",
          Regions: [
            {
              Country: "USA",
              RegionName: "ALbany",
              RegionGroupName: "NY",
              RegionType: "County"
            },
            {
              Country: "USA",
              RegionName: "Chenango",
              RegionGroupName: "NY",
              RegionType: "County"
            },
            {
              Country: "USA",
              RegionName: "Gloucester",
              RegionGroupName: "NJ",
              RegionType: "County"
            },
            {
              Country: "USA",
              RegionName: "Essex",
              RegionGroupName: "NJ",
              RegionType: "County"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {

  },
  computed: {

  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the beginning of what you're asking? It's a bit hard to tell from your question/example. You may need to use RegionGroupName instead of State... hard to tell from your question.

```
   <div v-for="state in states" :key="state">
    <p>{{ state }}</p>
    // For each state lookup all matching states in acList
    <div>{{ someMethod(state) }}</div>
   </div>

   someMethod(state) {
     return this.acList.filter((x) => x.State === state);
   }

   computed: {
     states() {
       return new Set(this.acList.map((x) => x.State).sort());
     },
   }
```

Comment: I stripped a ton of stuff out of the component to post it, but it looks like I had a couple things remaining that weren't relevant. I need three v-for elements nested inside each other, and the middle one eliminates duplicate RegionGroupName in acList.Regions. The one on the lowest level maps counties to the state.

Comment: ok, If I understand you correctly, this is what you want. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-o3f9o

Comment: Yes! Awesome answer! Thanks so much! I'm going to study what you did with those two methods!

Comment: Glad I could help. I tried to make it as straightforward as possible. Just let me know if you need any explanations as to what is happening.

Comment: ok, I've been looking what you did with sending the v-for through those methods, and thought, I could have a computed return a filtered array of all that have a RegionGroupname that match this.selectedState, but no such luck. Where am I going wrong with my thinking on working my way through the data?  https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-rnrh7

Comment: You are not using the es6 filter/map calls correctly. One explicit way would be to make a copy of the list and filter out the unwanted entries.  Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-g0nke

Comment: Why would that always return both companies regardless. Say you change selectedState to "MS", it seems like it never filters out the other company name that doesn't apply to selectedState? It's filtering the regions, but not filtering the company with the matching regions. By the way, thanks for the help clarifying this!

Comment: I updated the code, but you'd just add a filter at the end for checking if the regions for that entry have 1 or more entries.  return copy.filter(entry => entry.Regions.length > 0);

Comment: Thanks! I ended up getting it working with a v-if in the DOM after reading your initial comment and inspecting found. I'll give this way a shot. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Yep, no problem